# How can i pass two different variables to View

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i pass two different variables to View from controller(i am using codigniter framework).

My fist variable has some data records, and second variables has images data.

```
$dirname = "uploads/";
$images = glob($dirname."*"); // this is my second variable.
$this->load->view('includes/template',$data,$images); // this is not working.
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
$dirname = "uploads/";
$data['images'] = glob($dirname."*"); // this is my second variable.
$this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
```

You asccess this variable in your view by using `$images`

Comment: By this technique images are not appearing , when i access my view.

Comment: How are trying to display images in in your view?

Comment: With foreach.. foreach($images as $image){
    
//print the image to browser with anchor tag (Use if you want really :) )
echo '<a href="'.$image.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'" height="100" width="100"></a><br>';
}

Comment: print_r($images)in your vies and check what its value

Comment: print_r($image); value is Array ( [0] => uploads/1.png [1] => uploads/2.jpg [2] => uploads/3.jpg ) Array ( [0] => uploads/1.png [1] => uploads/2.jpg [2] => uploads/3.jpg )

Comment: use for loop for($i=0;$i<=count($images);$i++;)

Comment: <img src="'.$images[$i].'" height="100" width="100">

Answer (score 1):

it's quite simple.just do it this way-

```
$data['dirname'] = "uploads/";
$data['images'] = glob($dirname."*"); // this is my second variable.
$this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

make an array.

```
$data = array ("var"=>$somedata,"images"=>$images);
$this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array as the second argument to [view](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html):

```
$viewData = array(
               'data' => $data,
               'images' => $images,
               'someOther' => $someOtherData
          );

$this->load->view('includes/template', $viewData);
```

Comment: No change happens, same output is appearing.

Comment: Then the mistake is probably in your view. Add some debugging there (`var_dump($images)` etc.).